# What happens if range hood is smaller than cooktop?

Tags: kitchens, chimney, hood

If the range hood is 70% size of cooktop, shouldn't the smoke from sides of cooktop still get sucked towards middle hence getting sucked inside?

So why people recommend range hood bigger than cooktop?

Comment: It's _most likely_ also got to do with capturing the _heat_ from the cook top and protecting the wooden cabinets that are often installed above the stove from that heat. But, this is just my speculation, so hang on until you get a more authoritative answer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My answer would be **it depends** (e.g. on stove BTU, gas vs electric, hood CFM, etc); without a lot more info this will be too opinion-based for our site. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: If it's over-sized, you don't need a fan to trap greasy steam, and if you need a fan, it can be quieter. If the hood vents outside, a large one traps rising heat and cheaply removes it instead of you paying to re-air-condition it. In short, a large hood is cleaner, quieter, and cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

The Code requires an overhead exhaust hood to be “at least as wide as the unit and shall extend over the entire unit”. (See ICC M1504) There are exceptions (i.e.: downdraft, etc.) but must be labeled for such use.

In addition, it goes on to say the exhaust duct shall extend to the exterior with a backdraft damper and cannot be plastic.

Interesting side note: Section ICC M1504 says there shall be a minimum clear distance from the cooktop to combustible material or cabinets of 24”, but Section ICC M1901 says the distance shall be a minimum of 30”. Go figure.

Comment: Code seems to be a reasonable answer to a non-intuative question... ;)